# Como fazer o efeito de scroll animado automatico?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Este site que encontrei https://cliquestudios.com/ possui um efeito super bacana que gostaria de fazer um parecido em meu site:
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando você rola para baixo, o item 01 muda para 02. Consequentemente muda o conteúdo.

Sei que devo utilizar Javascript e CSS, mas não consigo encontrar algum tutorial que explique como funciona.

Alguém já fez ou tem algo parecido?

Comment: Esse site está bem aprimorado, para começar conheço o [Scrollspy](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_scrollspy.asp) que implementa mudança conforme scroll.

Answer (score 1):

O menu lateral com os itens é fixo pelo CSS: `position: fixed` e a altura da linha que indica qual item está aparecendo no momento é modificada a cada scroll da página. Assim como a função de clicar nos itens e animar a página também depende de scroll.

Uma maneira de fazer esse efeito é: `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#id').offset().top}, 'slow');`

Dê uma estudada nessas funções https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ e http://api.jquery.com/offset/ (offset pega as coordenadas do elemento escolhido)

Exemplo que achei no Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryantroyford/ZuZQJ/

Comment: Muito bom. Não conhecia esses métodos, bem legal essa funcionalidade do jquery.